# org-mode agenda in the background asynchronously

Tags: org-mode

Is a way to process the org-agenda asynchronously in the background as it takes a long time?

I'm using the latest emacs (master branch as of 1week ago and org version 9.0.5).

Comment: You could try to figure out which function is causing the most time consumption -- e.g., a poorly written org-agenda skip function.  `org-agenda` uses `re-search-forward` to gather data .. `re-search-backward` is faster in most instances because point is already at the beginning of headlines.  How about opening up multiple instances of Emacs so that you can keep working in another instance while your other instance is doing its thing, and then close whichever when your are done?  It's a lisp operation, not a background process, so i'ts going to lock-up your Emacs if it takes time to process.

Comment: Opening up another emacs is a bit of a pain as I use exwm so I live in emacs. I'll start looking at the org-mode code but I'm only just learning lisp. I was interested in the new async functions which have been added to the latest emacs. Maybe parts of org-agenda which are taking time could be handled by the new emacs async abilities. Is this even possible?

Comment: Did you find out how to do this? I want to process org files asynchronously for another purpose besides `org-agenda`.

Comment: @vv111y No I haven't found out yet. Still looking at how to do this.